# PDF of estimated Bernoulli parameter

Tags: density-function, bernoulli-process

This is my first question on this part of the stack exchange, so please bear with me and correct me if I am missing something obvious. Statistics is not my main field of expertise.

**Background**

I wish to estimate the Bernoulli parameter *${p}$* by performing *${n}$* Bernoulli trials, resulting in *${n_1}$* successes. I have no prior knowledge of *${p}$*.

**Problem**

From searching google and my textbooks I have found many methods for estimating *${p}$* and its confidence intervals. But this is not what I am after. What I wish to end up with is simply a probability density function of the estimated *${p}$*.

Thank you all for your time in advance.

Comment: Start by reviewing the top hits on our site concerning [Beta Binomial Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta+binomial+bayes*).